# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\scorpio to do\index.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, database, youtube

I'm following a series of videos on phpacademy.org, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaBWDOBFxDc&index=9&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc)

In the video above, after following it, I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\scorpio to do\index.php on line 4

my code is: 
index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM gebruikers");

?>
```

init.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'scorpiodb'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
?>
```

db.php:

```
<?php
    class db{
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo, 
                $_query, 
                $_error = false, 
                $_results, 
                $_count = 0;

        private function __construct(){
            try{
                $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. config::get('mysql/host') .';dbname='. config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance(){
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
                self::$_instance = new db();
            }
        }

        public function query($sql, $params = array()){
            $this->_error = false;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
                echo 'ok';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

everything worked fine before I included line 4 on index and the query function in db. Maybe there's a typing error I did or something I overlooked. Can you guys help me out please?

Comment: Should't `public static function getInstance()` function be returning `self::$_instance` ?

Comment: that's it, thanks, knew it was something I overlooked, there you have it